# TypeError: As of 3.10, the *loop* parameter was removed from Lock() since it is no longer necessary

Tags: binance

How do I solve this?

```
TypeError: As of 3.10, the *loop* parameter was removed from Lock() since it is no longer necessary
```

I'm trying to use Binance socket manager, and I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 13):

Should just be a case of upgrading your websockets version from 9.1 to 10.x

```
pip install --upgrade websockets
```

Answer (score 2):

`TypeError: As of 3.10, the *loop* parameter was removed from Queue() since it is no longer necessary`

I was getting this error when i try to use proxybroker package.

I just downgrade python version to 3.6.8 and now error is gone.

Maybe your error to occurred by python version.

maybe helps

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue. My bot ran fine on MacOS, but it popped up when I installed Fedora on the Apple instead. Never resolved it before moving on to other OS's, but I don't know if it would have happened on Ubuntu or Zorin, because a PIP problem stopped me long before then.
As for my primary, an MSI gaming laptop running Windows 11, I never had the issue on the command line python, IDLE, PyCharm, Visual Studio, nor Visual Studio Code, UNTIL this morning when my laptop overheated and shutdown. When I booted up again, the system no longer recognized the modules I had been using (pandas, pytz, python-binance) and they had to be installed again (from an elevated command line, which seemed odd). Then when running the program from VS, there comes the error again. Command prompt returns the same error, however, IDLE runs the program without issue. I'm not knowledgeable enough to say how to directly fix the bug, or even why it's happening, but it seems that there may be methods of skirting it. The error reads 'As of 3.10...' so if you cannot find an application that can run it, you might try rolling it back to 3.9. Sorry I can't be of any real aid, here. Hope you find your answers. I'll keep looking, too.

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with several solutions.

1. I created my own ticker:

   ```
    play = client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol='BTCUSDT)
    def start_ticker():
      global play
      while True:
        play = client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol='BTCUSDT')
        print(play['Price'])
        time.sleep(1)
    bsm = ThreadedWebsocketManager()
    bsm.start()
    start_ticker()
   ```

Now, this is just a sort of preliminary example. I've tied it into my actual trading loop and removed the print function, but store and process the data second by second. I run multiple tokens simultaneously and set the sleep at the end of the entire loop, after the condition evaluations have been processed. You can tweak the rest time after testing the duration of your loop, but overall it's hasn't ever shown to be critical for it to be off by fragments of a second. One caveat is that it only delivers the flat price, but you can check the documentation for additional queries you can pull from: [Python Binance 0.2.0 Websockets Documentation](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/websockets.html#threadedwebsocketmanager-websocket-usage)

2. Install Python 3.9:
   This is easiest on Windows, as no system processes rely on it. If you install it parallel to your current version, you'll have to take extra steps to address it rather than the later version, such as with PATH edits or virtual environments. An easy tool for this is Anaconda, which can create the virtual environment with little fuss.
   I run my trader on a PC running Fedora, which has proven to be more reliable with server connections (unfortunately, Windows 11 can't keep proper time without a looping PowerShell script that manually resyncs, and I get Windows semaphore errors even with the time issue fixed). However, Fedora relies on up-to-date Python for some system functions, so you have to install the pre-3.10 version beside it an create a symbolic link and a virtual environment to run it.
3. Modify the python-binance module to use a different Loop function, which I believe can be done with PyCharm or Anacondas, but from what I read it's not the best of ideas and I don't see a need for it at the moment. Also, I would probably just break it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure u installed asyncio and imported that. I had the same problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).