# ProxyBroker Script - same error, even if code is written in many different ways

Tags: python, web-scraping, firefox, proxy

a quick aside first - has anyone used Proxybroker? I pip installed it, but any code I find with it gives me the same error... I'll post the exact code -

```
import asyncio
from proxybroker import Broker

async def show(proxies):
    while True:
        proxy = await proxies.get()
        if proxy is None: break
        print('Found proxy: %s' % proxy)

proxies = asyncio.Queue()
broker = Broker(proxies)
tasks = asyncio.gather(
    broker.find(types=['HTTP', 'HTTPS'], limit=10),
    show(proxies))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
```

& the error I recieve is ...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zed/Project/proxybroker2.py", line 27, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/zed/Project/proxybroker2.py", line 19, in main
    broker = Broker(proxies)
  File "/home/zed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/proxybroker/api.py", line 97, in __init__
    self._on_check = asyncio.Queue(maxsize=max_conn, loop=self._loop)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/queues.py", line 34, in __init__
    super().__init__(loop=loop)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/mixins.py", line 17, in __init__
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: As of 3.10, the *loop* parameter was removed from Queue() since it is no longer necessary
```

& this is the same error, even if I run different code... ex.

```
from proxybroker import Broker


async def save(proxies, filename):
    """Save proxies to a file."""
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        while True:
            proxy = await proxies.get()
            if proxy is None:
                break
            proto = 'https' if 'HTTPS' in proxy.types else 'http'
            row = '%s://%s:%d\n' % (proto, proxy.host, proxy.port)
            f.write(row)


def main():
    proxies = asyncio.Queue()
    broker = Broker(proxies)
    tasks = asyncio.gather(broker.find(types=['HTTP', 'HTTPS'], limit=10),
                           save(proxies, filename='proxies.txt'))
#    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
#    loop.run_until_complete(tasks)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

even things as simple as

`proxybroker find --types HTTP HTTPS --lvl High --countries US --strict -l 10`

gives me the SAME error...

I have this code for a proxy scraper in Python w/ Firefox Geckodriver.

Basically the exact same as is listed above /\ <3

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/71535250/494134

Comment: similar, but different modules, different error "Lock()" instead of "Queue()", etc. maybe tho - I tried the answer and it didn't work T.T I greatly appreciate your resourcefulness tho in finding me an answer <3